# UIKit Dropdown not dropping down

Tags: html, angularjs, uikit

I have created a dropdown with UIKit but when the button is clicked nothing happens. I have been checking out the Docs and examples and I cannot see anything that is being done wrong.

The code:

```
  <div>
    <div class="uk-margin">
      <div class="data-uk-dropdown">
        <!-- This is the element toggling the dropdown -->
        <div class="uk-button-dropdown">
          <button class="uk-button">
            Cart
            <i class="uk-icon-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="uk-dropdown">
            <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-dropdown">
              <li>Test1</li>
              <li>test2</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need an unique param: data-uk-dropdown.

Like this:
`<div data-uk-dropdown class="someclass">`

UiKit 2 :
https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/dropdown.html

UiKit 3 :
https://getuikit.com/docs/dropdown